# 3d graph, mix between bar and surf

Tags: matlab, graph, 3d

I have 3 functions f1=f1(x), f2=f2(x) and f3=f3(x). I can plot three 2d graphs on a single figure with the command `hold on`, but I would like to plot three graphs in a single 3d graph.

I can plot a 3d surface with `surf` command.

```
x = -3:0.1:3;
y = [1,2,3];
z = [f1(x);f2(x);f3(x)];

surf(x,y,z)
```

Since the y variable does not lay in a range, but has discrete values, this graph does not make sense.

It would be better a 3d graph like the previous one for the x variable and something like a bar chart for the y variable.
Is it possible to plot a "mixed" graph like that?

To better explain what I would like to obtain, I add this graph found with the help of Google

[image]

Comment: Can't you make do with `bar3`? It gives flat tops, but other than that it's more or less what you want, isn't it?

Comment: Or maybe `ribbon`, if you only need the (curved) top

Comment: @LuisMendo with the flat tops of bar3 I lose too much, but ribbon is perfect! Thank you very much! If you want to write it as answer I'll accept it!

Comment: Great! I've posted it as an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`ribbon`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ribbon.html) function does what you want, except that it only shows the top part:

```
>> ribbon(peaks(15)) %// using the `peaks` function as an example
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice.  I was looking at something like [`waterfall`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/waterfall.html) while trying to answer this question but I couldn't get it to look like the OP's plot.  Nice function this `ribbon`!

Comment: @rayryeng Thanks! I began with `waterfall` too, but somehow remembered about `ribbon` (which has a nice name BTW!)